# Grow an HFS+ Volume on OSX without re-partitioning

Tags: filesystems, osx, hfs+

I have created a master image using Clonezilla so we can (frequently) re-image a bunch of our machines.

The problem I am having lies in the deployment of the image to machines with larger HDDs.  The master image was created on a 250GB HDD.  (Of which we have several machines.)  We also have quite a few machines with 500GB HDDs.

The image works fine across the machines, with the exception of the size of the filesystem.  On the 500GB machines, the partition table is kept intact during the imaging, but the filesystem reports just 250GB when the image is done.

OSX allows online resizing of the partitions and filesystems, but it will puke in this case since the partition and filesystems are different sizes.

Both the "Disk Utility" application, as well as the `diskutil resizeDisk` command fail.  (With rather generic error messages.)

So here is my question: How do I resize JUST the filesystem on OSX?

An online resize is obviously possible for HFS+, but I can't find documentation anywhere on how to do JUST this.